# Jquery Mobile - How do I get the form element of the active Page without using the form id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to get the form element of the active page without using the form id. Basically I'm dealing with dynamic external content and can't rely on the form id as it may change. Also, it's possible that there may not be a form on the page.

`$.mobile.activePage`.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$.mobile.activePage.find("form")
```

or

```
$("form", $.mobile.activePage)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if there is only one form element on the page, you can do a

```
$.mobile.activePage.find("form")
```

If there are more than one form elements, obviously this will return an array object containing the forms, then you'll just need to filter, or just make the above js call more specific.